# Fancybox link in link tag

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

On my website users can favorite images (user hovers over image, option to favorite an image shows).
My current code (in a foreach loop):

```
    <a class="fancybox" title="Titel {{ $afbeelding }}" rel="group" href="{{asset('assets/images/badkamer/full').'/'.$afbeelding->url}}" >
        <div class="favorieten-hover-box">
            <img src="{{asset('assets/images/badkamer/thumb').'/'.$afbeelding->url}}">  
            <div>
                <span>                               
                    <a rel="group" href="<?php if (!Auth::check()){echo URL::to('login');} else{ echo "javascript:void(0);";}?>"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-heart-o favoriet-knop" title="Toevoegen aan favorieten" id="{{$afbeelding->id}}"></i></a>
                    <a rel="group" href="{{URL::to('badkamer/'.$afbeelding->kamer->id.'/'.str_replace(' ','-',$afbeelding->kamer->naam))}}"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-right  fa-lg" title="Badkamer bekijken"></i></a> 
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
```

As you see there is an `<a>` tag in an `<a>` tag and what happens is fancybox adds all the inner `<a>` tags as an image to the gallery of fancybox. So if I click on an image there is 3 of them in the gallery.
What can I do to keep the tags like this but avoid having the same image 3 times in one gallery.

**edit**: the a tags work perfectly they link to the right action, the only problem is that all images appear 3 times in the fancybox gallery.

Comment: Just remove `rel="group"` from the inner `<a>` tags so they will be excluded from the gallery

Comment: @JFK unfortunately not making any difference, i guess they inherit it from the parent <a> tag

Comment: OK, checked that. What would you an html structure like that? (curious)

Comment: @JFK its a box that will floot on top of the image on hover with a button to add to favorit.

Comment: Anchor tags aren't allowed in other anchor tags. You're asking for trouble.

Comment: I recognize that "without changing the dom structure" is a constraint you've requested on answers, but that just isn't going to happen. Your DOM structure is invalid.

Comment: **Always fix invalid markup first.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since nesting `<a>` tags inside another `<a>` tag leads to an almost impossible solution, as a workaround you can use another element (as suggested by [MauricioCarnieletto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2543117/mauriciocarnieletto)) to wrap your nested `<a>` tags.

Then bind that wrapper (`class="fancybox"`) element to fancybox BUT using the special fancybox's `data` attributes :

- `data-fancybox-href`
- `data-fancybox-title`
- `data-fancybox-group`

Like :

```
<div class="fancybox" data-fancybox-title="Titel {{ $afbeelding }}" data-fancybox-group="group" data-fancybox-href="{{asset('assets/images/badkamer/full').'/'.$afbeelding->url}}" >
    <div class="favorieten-hover-box">
        <img src="{{asset('assets/images/badkamer/thumb').'/'.$afbeelding->url}}" alt="" />  
        <div>
            <span>                               
                <a href="<?php if (!Auth::check()){echo URL::to('login');} else{ echo "javascript:void(0);";}?>"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-heart-o favoriet-knop" title="Toevoegen aan favorieten" id="{{$afbeelding->id}}"></i></a>
                <a href="{{URL::to('badkamer/'.$afbeelding->kamer->id.'/'.str_replace(' ','-',$afbeelding->kamer->naam))}}"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-right  fa-lg" title="Badkamer bekijken"></i></a> 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your script can be as simple as :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a4bvL8wy/)**

**Notice** I removed the `rel="group"` attributes from the nested links since you don't need them unless you are using them for another purpose other than fancybox.

---

**EDIT** : since you have nested links inside the wrapper, you may want them to have a separated action without firing fancybox as well as showing them on `hover` as you previously stated in one of your comments so

first you may need to tweak your css like

```
.fancybox:hover .fa {
    display: block;
    /* other css properties */
}
```

**notice** I am targeting the class `.fa`, which is common to both nested links.

Then tweak your fancybox initialization code like

```
$(".fancybox").on("click", ".fa", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // don't fire fancybox
}).fancybox();
```

**notice** we used `.stopPropagation()` to prevent selectors `.fa` from firing fancybox but still perform their default actions.

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a4bvL8wy/5/)**

Comment: @SvenB maybe you need to change `a.fancybox:hover` into `.fancyboox:hover`

Answer (score 1):

As per the W3C specifications: [Nested Links are Illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2).

> Links and anchors defined by the A element must not be nested; an A
>   element must not contain any other A elements.
>
> Since the DTD defines the LINK element to be empty, LINK elements may
>   not be nested either.

As such, there's no correct way to "fix" your issue short of complying with the standards and not putting anchor tags inside other anchor tags - that doesn't make sense and isn't going to play nicely, as you're discovering. You need to figure out how to structure your HTML differently to fit within the standards for the elements you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Like sphanley said, you can't nest two links, but, you can solve this with js, and changing the element.

Change your HTML to this firs:

```
<span class="callthisanewclass" title="Titel {{ $afbeelding }}" rel="group" data-href="{{asset('assets/images/badkamer/full').'/'.$afbeelding->url}}" >
        <div class="favorieten-hover-box">
            <img src="{{asset('assets/images/badkamer/thumb').'/'.$afbeelding->url}}">  
            <div>
                <span>                               
                    <a rel="group" href="<?php if (!Auth::check()){echo URL::to('login');} else{ echo "javascript:void(0);";}?>"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-heart-o favoriet-knop" title="Toevoegen aan favorieten" id="{{$afbeelding->id}}"></i></a>
                    <a rel="group" href="{{URL::to('badkamer/'.$afbeelding->kamer->id.'/'.str_replace(' ','-',$afbeelding->kamer->naam))}}"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-right  fa-lg" title="Badkamer bekijken"></i></a> 
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
```

Then, add this to your JS (in this case, Jquery)

```
$('.callthisanewclass').on('click', function () {

    var ths = $(this),
        href = ths.data('href');

    ths.fancybox({

       href: href

    });

}
```